# How to copy files and folder from one ADLS to another one on different subscription?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I need to be able to copy files and folder from one DataLake to another DataLake on a different subscription, I'm in possession of both Auth Token and secret key.

I've tried different solution including:

https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4

which is involving hadoop but didn't worked on two different subscriptions, due to the site-core.xml which only accept one subscription.

ADLcopy didn't worked as well, neither DataFactory.

Any ideas? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What were your errors from Data Factory? It should support this

Comment: @AnnaZietlow Is not properly an error.. I can't seem to find a solution to add both Secret Keys and tokens in the core-sites xml..

Comment: Errors from Data Factory, not Hadoop :)

Comment: I have moved data across ADLS subscriptions in ADF before. Can you provide the exact error message? Also I added the ADF tag since that looks more like an ADF issue.

Comment: @MichaelRys is not an error, I'm trying to add both secret key and tokens  of the two dirrent subscriptions in the core-site.xml

Comment: core-site.xml is a Hadoop feature. Not an Azure Data Factory feature... You don't need Hadoop to use Azure Data Factory to move data.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory supports such scenario, you need to create 2 AzureDataLakeStoreLinkedService, each with correct corresponding subscription and resource group (they don't necessarily be the same with the subscription of the data factory), and the credential of the service principal to access ADLS. 
If this doesn't answer your question, could you tell more of your scenario, as I don't understand this: " I'm trying to add both secret key and tokens of the two dirrent subscriptions in the core-site.xml", do you mean

Comment: Having credentials of SP from another subscription is not secure.